# nhibernate event listener registration

Tags: .net, nhibernate, events, listener, soft-delete

I am trying to override the delete event listener with a custom soft delete listener I wrote; however, I am having issues with the registration process.  I have the following in my web.config:

```
  <event type="delete">
    <listener class="NHibernateTest1.Model.MyDeleteEventListener"/>
  </event>
```

I have tried to register the listener programmatically as well:

```
  NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration config = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
  config.SetListener(ListenerType.Delete, new MyDeleteEventListener());
```

I tested this and my deletes are still hard deletes, in fact I do not think my listener was even registered.  Any ideas what might be going on?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same issues. Listeners won't fire.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the assembly name in the config file. Should be something like:

```
<event type="delete">
    <listener class="NHibernateTest1.Model.MyDeleteEventListener, YourAssembly"/>
</event>
```

I have my events setup this way and it works flawlessly.